Mega Man Maker crashes on launch with PlayOnMac
I'm trying to run Mega Man Maker 1.9.3.1 on a Mac running macOS 14.1 and PlayOnMac 4.4.4. I used the Install button, went through the workflow, selected my downloaded ZIP file, and completed the installation. However, the game immediately crashes on launch with:

Error in main
Mega Man Maker crashed.
Select its shortcut and click on "Debug" in the side panel to get more details.

Doing that produces this result:
[10/25/24 21:03:30] - Running wine-3.0.3 MegaMaker.exe (Working directory : /Users/redacto/Library/PlayOnMac/wineprefix/mega_man_maker/drive_c/game)
009c:err:plugplay:process_IOService_Device object 0x4f03
009c:err:plugplay:process_IOService_Device object 0x7e03
009c:err:plugplay:process_IOService_Device object 0x7d03
009c:err:plugplay:process_IOService_Device object 0x7b03
009c:err:plugplay:process_IOService_Device object 0x5903
009c:err:plugplay:process_IOService_Device object 0x7903
009c:err:plugplay:process_IOService_Device object 0x7803
009c:err:plugplay:process_IOService_Device object 0x7703
009c:err:plugplay:process_IOService_Device object 0x8703
009c:err:plugplay:process_IOService_Device object 0x8f03
009c:err:plugplay:process_IOService_Device object 0x9c03
009c:err:plugplay:process_IOService_Device object 0x9b03
009c:err:plugplay:process_IOService_Device object 0x9a03
009c:err:plugplay:process_IOService_Device object 0x9403
009c:err:plugplay:process_IOService_Device object 0x9903
009c:err:plugplay:process_IOService_Device object 0x9803
009c:err:plugplay:process_IOService_Device object 0xaa03
009c:err:plugplay:process_IOService_Device object 0xfe03
009c:err:plugplay:process_IOService_Device object 0xab03
009c:err:plugplay:process_IOService_Device object 0xfc03
009c:err:plugplay:process_IOService_Device object 0xae03
009c:err:plugplay:process_IOService_Device object 0xfa03
009c:err:plugplay:process_IOService_Device object 0xf903
00c4:err:process:exec_process L"C:\\game\\MegaMaker.exe" not supported on this system
00cc:err:process:exec_process L"C:\\game\\MegaMaker.exe" not supported on this system

Question: What do I need to change to get this game to work? In case this is useful, Mega Man Maker was made with Mega Engine, which was made in Game Maker Studio 2 (reference). Thanks!
I am going to be posting a similar question about an error trying to run this game with Wine directly.

Is Mega Man Maker like Super Mario Maker, but Maga Man instead of Mario? I never heard of this.

@Alex Yes, it's exactly like that! It's excellent in my humble opinion!

I love Mega Man. I'll have to check out the game myself. I might be able to help you out for all I know (if my answer doesn't help you out in anyway).

I can think of three things that normally cause these errors.

You might need to check if there are any updates for Mega Man Maker, PlayOnMac, and Wine.

Often times errors like the ones you gave will appear due to corrupted files. Maybe re-download the Mega Man Maker files if possible.

Try updating or reinstalling Wine. Sometimes settings or other information could be the cause of the issue, and may need to be reset.



Thank you for your reply, Alex. These were all fresh installs. I also understand from another question I made that technical troubleshooting is off-topic for Arqade.

I did post to Reddit and pursued a suggestion there and ended up installed Whisky, which is similar to Bottles, and it works great!

For reference, https://www.reddit.com/r/MegaMakerOfficial/comments/1gfj23n/getting_mmm_working_on_macos_141_mac_mini_m2/.

@ThatBroadfromQueens So the game works now? If so, then great!
